# How to create a software raid5 array without a spare

Tags: linux, software-raid, mdadm

I am trying to create a software raid5 array using mdadm:

```
$ linux # mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 --spare-devices=0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
mdadm: layout defaults to left-symmetric
mdadm: chunk size defaults to 64K
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
```

However when inspecting /proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid5 sdd1[4] sdc1[2] sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      2930279808 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [UUU_]
      [>....................]  recovery =  0.3% (2970496/976759936) finish=186.1min speed=87172K/sec

unused devices: <none>
```

It seems one drive isn't active, so I check the details of the array:

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 00.90.03
  Creation Time : Tue Jul 21 16:29:53 2009
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 2930279808 (2794.53 GiB 3000.61 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 976759936 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Tue Jul 21 16:29:53 2009
          State : clean, degraded, recovering
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

 Rebuild Status : 0% complete

           UUID : ce8b2f40:821d003c:0027688e:a70977ec
         Events : 0.1

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       2       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       4       8       49        3      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdd1
```

And it seems there are only 3 active devices, with one spare.

Is it just me, or something wrong here?

Comment: seems like you're missing some info

Comment: Yeah, pressed enter too soon :-) Here is the entire question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.howinthetech.com/quick-and-dirty-linux-software-raid5/) covers building a raid5 array with mdadm. You can't use raid5 with less than three devices.

What do you mean by a spare? Raid5 is designed to provide redundancy to survive the failure of one device. If it doesn't do that then it isn't raid5 anymore.

---

Edit after question edit:

```
   When creating a RAID5 array, mdadm will automatically create a degraded
   array with an extra spare drive.  This is because  building  the  spare
   into a degraded array is in general faster than resyncing the parity on
   a non-degraded, but not clean, array.  This feature can  be  overridden
   with the --force option.
```

That seems to be it, mdadm is setting up the new array as degraded with a spare, and then putting the spare in to build the array.

Comment: Yes, but apart from the parity info distributed under the 4 drives, it seems it is talking about a spare drive. (Active: 3, Working: 4, Spare Devices: 1)

And I am wondering if something is wrong...

Comment: Also, as you can see in the tutorial you linked, /proc/mdadm suggest the 3 drives are all fine [UUU] whereas my array says one isn't active [UUU_].

I was fearing a faulty drive, but it seems it is spare.

Comment: Nothing to worry about then.

Thanks :-)

Comment: This is not correct, see my post below. You can create a degraded RAID5 with 2 drives. You can also create a RAID5 with two members (--level=5 --raid-devices=2 ...). In cat /proc/mdstat it'll say it's using RAID5, but it'll behave like a RAID1 (e.g. you'll see UU and not UU_).

Answer (score 4):

if you got clean disks, and you are making a brand new array, the faster option around the initial rebuild is

(in my case)

```
mdadm --create --verbose --force --assume-clean /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=4 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
```

Comment: In my case creating a brand new, clean array, was what I was actually looking for, and, actually, what I expected from `mdadm` to do in the first place.

Comment: the `--force` and `--assume-clean` were what I needed.

Comment: doesn't `--assume-clean` mean that the parity is clean, meaning already written? I believe this approach will skip the initial write of parity and prevent you from ever being able to recover a failed drive

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a degraded RAID5 from known clean disks/partitions you need at least 2 drives (e.g. for a 3 drive RAID5), you'd do :

```
mdadm --create --verbose --force --assume-clean /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 missing
```

Answer (score 1):

It also shows as currently recovering and your spare drive is showing rebuilding.  I'd be interested to see what your output looks like after it finishes.

Comment: I will paste the output after it finishes.

Comment: I just confirmed on a test box what I suspect you will see and that is that once the recovery is done, the fourth device will not be listed as a spare any more.  Precisely as the answer above states.